# Explicitly hide a base function in C++

Tags: c++

C++11 introduced very useful specifier `override` for *explicitly override* a base virtual function. But what about *explicit hiding*?

For example, consider the code:

```
struct A: B {
    void f();
}
```

1. If there is a virtual `void B::f()` the code cause implicit *overriding* this function.
2. If there is a non-virtual `void B::f()` the code cause *hiding* this function.

That is, the meaning of the code depends on existence and virtuality of `void B::f()`.

**Question.** How to explicitly hide a base function? I want to get error if I try to hide virtual function.

Such as `override` is the *guard* to ensure that *there is* virtual base function with the same prototype, I need a *guard* to ensure that *there is no* virtual base function with the same prototype.

---

Epic fail example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct B {
    void f() {printf("Hello\n");}
    void g() {f();}
};

struct A: B {
    void f() {g();}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

The program print "Hello". But if I make `B::f()` virtual the program cause segmentation fault (infinite recursion). This may be a real problem if `B` class is third-party and I just #include it, that is changing the virtuality in the third-party code may cause fault in my code.

**UPD.** I found that C# [have this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) via `new` specifier. It's seems that C++ have not (yet?).

Comment: Because if `B::f()` is virtual and `A::f` overrides it then `A::f` calls `g::f` which calls `A::f` which calls `g::f` which calls `A::f`.. aka infinite recursion.. It does not call `B::f`.

Comment: You may qualify: `void g() { B::f(); }`

Comment: @DieterLücking: I've updated my post. It's not always possible to control code of base class.

Comment: @Corvus Then, you have to break the circle - means - you can't call `B::g()`

Comment: @DieterLücking: `B::g()` is arbitrary base function. I may even don't know that it call `f()`. Do you advice me to not call base functions at all?..

Comment: @Corvus just test it and see if it loops?

Comment: @PawełStawarz: read the full question and comments before adding a new comment.

Comment: @Corvus as a matter a fact I did. Maybe you should try doing the same? That's the most obvious answer to your problem. Write the code normally, test it. If it behaves in a bad way - stop calling the function. To be honnest I can't think of a __real life__ example of your situation.

Comment: It could be done by some static analyser tool (libclang provide a nice interface to write your own tools)...

Comment: @Corvus, normally specialization happens in derived classes not base classes.  An approach would be to have the `sync` be a virtual that in most instances is a dummy or stub however for the particular device would actually do something useful.  That way your base class is now back to being truly a base class that as part of what it does and calls a `sync` whose default is to do nothing but which can be overwritten if necessary.

Comment: There is no virtual class in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may use to check the base class :

```
// Class to check that B::f() is not virtual
// struct A requires that this class compiles, else struct A should epic fails.
struct checkInterfaceIsNotVirtual_B : B
{
    void f() = delete;
};
```

It will fail to compile if `B::f()` is virtual :

- g++:

  ```
  error: deleted function 'virtual void checkInterfaceIsNotVirtual_B::f()'
  ```
- clang++:

  ```
  error: deleted function 'f' cannot override a non-deleted function
  ```

Comment: Note that that only works if the signature of `f()` exactly matches the base function.  If the base function is (for example) `void B::f() const`, `checkInterfaceIsNotVintual_B` will end up *hiding* `f()` without overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

§8.4.1.1 of the C++11 standard defines the function/method definition form:

> ### 8.4 Function definitions
>
> #### 8.4.1 In general
>
> <sup>1</sup> Function definitions have the form
>
> *function-definition*:
>     attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> declarator
> virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> function-body
>   *function-body*:
>     ctor-initializer<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement
>     function-try-block
>     `= default ;`
>     `= delete ;`

*virt-specifier* is defined in §9.2 as:

> *virt-specifier*:
>     `override`
>     `final`

So, no, there is no keyword similar to `override` for hiding.

Comment: But may be there is GCC extension for that? Or maybe this feature is planned to introduce in a future version of the standard?

Comment: I can't think of any. Maybe `-Wshadow` could warn you when it happens, but I don't have GCC on my machine to verify that it *will* warn you of this case, and it will warn you of so many other things that you might not want.