# In C++ Is there a (new) way to test if a class has a virtual destructor in a template without instantiating an instance?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have done some looking around and many discussions say "no you can't do that" but it is all evolving fast and I would like to test for this characteristic in a template that does not have access to a pointer to an instance of the object.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911112/how-to-detect-if-a-method-is-virtual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C++11, or later, the [`std::has_virtual_destructor<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_virtual_destructor) template provides this information.

Comment: lots of goodies in the traits header.  answers a lot of questions :)  A corrolary question to this might be is if an object has a virtual destructor  do all objects with virtual destructors keep them in the same place in the first vtable so without knowing exactly which base class the pointer came from can one invoke it knowing only the pointer (void *) and whether the template test ( which does know about the base class when it was made was true)  The same also might go for invoking any RTTI calls which require a vtable. be present.